# Simple Conditional AWK command

Tags: awk

I am a new GAWK user and have been able to figure out how to match patterns from several columns out of a 100 column report, but would like to learn how to simplify the code instead of appending the results of individual GAWK commands.

My current problem was to strip out header information, plus all instances of '/' characters in a variety of specific columns.

This reduced compound code example works:

```
gawk -F"|" '$1 ~ "Value" {print $1" | "$8" | "$51" | "$55}' "Q:\Report.txt" > c:\temp\Matches.txt && gawk -F"|" '$8 ~ "/" {print $1" | "$8" | "$51" | "$55}' "Q:\Report.txt" >> c:\temp\Matches.txt && gawk -F"|" '$51 ~ "/" {print $1" | "$8" | "$51" | "$55}' "Q:\Report.txt" >> c:\temp\Matches.txt && gawk -F"|" '$55 ~ "/" {print $1" | "$8" | "$51" | "$55}' "Q:\Report.txt" >> c:\temp\Matches.txt
```

Given my limited understanding on how to apply AWK expressions and syntax, attempts to simplify the above code (using multiple examples from various sources) have failed outright or in some ways.

The following code hangs:

```
gawk -F"|" '$1 ~ "Value" || $8 ~ "/" || $51  ~ "/" || $55 ~ "/" {print $1" | "$8" | "$51" | "$55}' "Q:\Report.txt"
```

After cancelling the process the following (and similar) error messages are produced:

> '$8' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

This following code find the appropriate matches, but it includes all 100 columns from my source data instead of just the ones noted:

```
gawk -F"|" '$1 ~ "Value";$8 ~ "/";$51  ~ "/";$55 ~ "/" {print $1" | "$8" | "$51" | "$55}' "Q:\Report.txt" > c:\temp\Matches.txt
```

In addition to any suggestions on simplifying the above code, what GAWK resources or books have the most useful code examples?

Much thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts, please do add your samples of input and expected output also in your question to make it clear, thank you.

Comment: please provide sample inputs and outputs; in this case we don't need to see 100 columns and 100s of lines, instead, provide a sample file with 5-10 columns and 5-10 lines which demonstrates the different scenarios you're trying to address; then show the expected output corresponding to this sample input file; see [How do I create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for more details

Comment: My apologies for not including a sample data set (I will keep that in mind with any future questions), but at this point the solution from dave_thompson_085 has resolved my issue.    Thank you for looking at my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You are apparently running on Windows CMD** although you didn't say so. CMD does not implement quoting the same way as Unix shells do and in particular doesn't handle single-quote `' ... '` in the way you need. C implementations for Windows, and therefore ports of Unix-based C programs like gawk to such implementations, usually try to approximate Unix shell command-line handling as closely as they can, but it's not sufficient for this case.

If on supported Windows (at least 8 up) **the simplest solution is to use PowerShell instead**. (This is also the Microsoft-recommended method, FWTW.) PowerShell even at the lexical level relevant here does have some significant differences from Unix -- especially backquote/backtick -- but it should be close enough to handle this case. (At the higher 'cmdlet' level it is quite different, being based on structured data not text.)

An alternative solution, arguably more programmy and thus ontopic, is to use the fact awk like C treats booleans as the integers 0 and 1 and use arithmetic addition instead:

```
 gawk -F"|" '($1 ~ "Value")+($8 ~ "/")+($51  ~ "/")+($55 ~ "/") {print $1" | "$8" | "$51" | "$55}' "Q:\Report.txt"
```

PS: I would also use OFS rather than retyping `" | "`:

```
-vOFS=" | " '...{print $1,$8,$51,$55}'
```

Comment: To remove the single quotes, we can use the regex-literal syntax instead of quoted strings: `gawk -F"|" -v OFS=" | " "$1 ~ /Value/ || $8 ~ /\// || $51  ~ /\// || $55 ~ /\// {print $1,$8,$51,$55}" "Q:\Report.txt"`

Comment: Yes, I'm using Windows with Cygwin64.  Thank you for your solution! (and the -vOFS tip)  It reduced my original command from 1310 characters down to 223 characters, plus stripped out duplicate records that had '/' in multiple columns, thus keeping the results in sequential order.   **If you could also provide Powershell code to do the same, it would be appreciated.**   Thankfully such specific queries can be done quickly from a command line without importing it into Excel or other software.

Answer (score 0):

since the 4 columns you're searching are also what you need in the end anyway, you can pre-trim the row first before doing a unified regex :

> ```
> mawk '(NF =($2=$8 substr(_, $3=$51, $4=$58))^_+3)*/^[^|]*Value|\|.*\//' OFS=' | '
> ```

```
Value1 | /8 | /51 | /58
```

the `substr()` is just a placeholder structure - it doesn't corrupt the data contained within `$8`, while the multiplication of 1st half and `regex` ensure `regex` must evaluate to true before the new synthetic row is printed